# Scale winform to lower resolution and all controls in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I made an application in Vb.net with winforms at a resolution of 1920x1080 not thinking it may need to run at a smaller resolution. When I run it at 1280x800 all the controls flows off the screen and doesn't fit even if I anchor/dock or use auto-sizing. I have tried putting my user controls in a panel and anchoring that too. Can you please give me advice on what I can do next, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Probably a TableLayoutPanel is in your future.

Comment: ...or some tabcontrols

Comment: Unfortunately, the short answer is... "Not really". You could put it on a panel and set `AutoScroll = True` but it's not going to look nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could collapse or hide part of the form. Surely filling a 1080p panel is information overload. Also consider placing related controls in their own forms.